# Trying to insert R Shiny Apps in Slidify

Tags: r, shiny, slidify

I am having difficulty finding good examples of how to embed R Shiny Apps in a Slidify presentation.  Ideally I would like to reference the external app.R file instead of recreating my existing code in the index.Rmd. 
Can anyone provide examples, include which widgets I need to include, and if I can also have data (as an excel file) accompany the embedded app (using a relative path?).

Is Slidify development still ongoing? Most posts I find are from 2 or more years ago.

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Tim did you ever get anywhere with this?  I'm trying to solve the same problem, where the shiny/slidify examples no longer work.

Comment: Hi Bob. Sorry to say I did not pursue it further. I'm creating my presentations now in RevealJS where I expect the same problems as slidify.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim, I realized that at this point there isn't much reason to use slidify, because the functionality has been rolled into regular rmarkdown, which supports ioslides.

Comment: Actually - I think I'm going to make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this in some detail because I was dealing with a similar issue.

The short version is, `slidify` is not longer really compatible with `shiny`, but the bulk of its functionality has been rolled-into `rmarkdown`, which is compatible with `shiny`.

Ramnath's last comments about this with `slidify`, were that it would require very substantial changes to the code to make it work.  That was 2015. `shiny` has changed substantially since then. So they're pretty out of sync.

The bright side is that `rmarkdown` now incorporates the bulk of the `slidify` functionality. It supports the `ioslides` and `slidy` slide frameworks. (`ioslides` is very similar to `slidify`'s `io2012`). The functionality that hasn't been included, is support for multiple slide layouts using moustache. But that isn't too big a deal, because you can just write the html directly into your `rmarkdown` slides. Its also a lot easier to customize than it was with `slidify`.  `shiny`, `htmlwidgets`, etc., all work transparently. If the visualization packages support it, its also very easy to switch between display in `shiny`, and packaging the presentation as a single `html5` document for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You might go through this examples here by Ramnath

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I95GOmLc7TA

Comment: That is a very useful tutorial. However, it covers inclusion of a googleVis motion chart, not an R Shiny App. Ramnath has suggested to me to use <iframe> , which may work for a URL to an App on a Shiny Server?  I am looking for how to run this on my local machine. I am running a local http service so I can successfully bring in D3js presentations. So far, including Shiny apps has eluded me.

Comment: Thats the only one I really have knowledge about